# Oldest and second oldest entry in a table?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a simple table that has columns user_id and the attempted date/time. For any particular user_id, there is at least one attempt but there can be more attempts (up to 6 attempts). I am trying to find JUST the two oldest attempt times for each user. How do I do this? I have written the below but this ONLY finds the oldest attempted date/time for any particular user. I need this but ALSO the second oldest attempt (if there is one).

```
SELECT user_id, MIN(attempt_datetime)
FROM table
GROUP by user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by attempt_datetime) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Retreive the 2 most recent rows by joining to a subquery that retrieves the latest two dates:

```
select
    a.*
from mytable a
join (
    select attempt_datetime
    from mytable
    where user_id = a.user_id
    order by attempt_datetime desc
    limit 2
) b on a.attempt_datetime = b.attempt_datetime
```